# "and not " vs "or" t sql full text search

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, query-performance, sqlperformance

I got struck in a query performance issue. My where clause contains,

```
where .....(type = c) and not (( type = a ) or contains ( ftstype, N'b' ))
```

the query seems to be faster without the "and not" part.

I would like to check if "and" is less costlier than "or", so that I can use the following (as per demorgans rule, [c and (a or b)' = c and (a' and b')] )

```
where .....(type = c) and ( not ( type = a ) and not contains ( ftstype, N'b' ))
```

I also want to check if the query optimizer takes this conversion in account, as well to determine the better plan for execution. (I am noob in understanding SQL server estimation plans.)

Comment: you should gice  the sql server estimations plan of each cersion of your request.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken (being somewhat of a beginner, myself), the 'or' option would be less costly. With the 'or' option, you would short circuit processing the full query if, say, type is not 'a' before even getting to the "not contains ( ftstype N'b'))" portion of the code.

What about something like this...

```
WHERE ..... (type = c) AND (( type != 'a' ) OR ( ftstype != N'b'))
```

Let me know what you discover, as I'm still learning, as well.